# read_csv() parsing failures - using problems() doesn't reveal what the issue is

Tags: r, date, parsing, readr

I am trying to read in a dataset that has a column with a date in it. As a default, this column is read in as character but I want it read in as date.

If I read in by using read_csv using the defaults, the dates in the column display like so in the viewer:12/04/2019  (i.e., dmy)

However, when using the following I get parsing failures:

```
data<- read_csv("file.csv", 
            col_types = cols(dob = col_date("%d-%m-%Y"))

Warning: 4160 parsing failures.
row col           expected     actual                                                                                                                                                                                       
  1 dob date like %d-%m-%Y 12/04/2019
```

At first, I thought this was because I had specified hyphens (-) in col_date. But I get the same errors if I change the hyphen to a forward slash:

```
data<- read_csv("file.csv", 
            col_types = cols(dob = col_date("%d/%m/%Y"))

Warning: 4160 parsing failures.
row col           expected     actual                                                                                                                                                                                       
  1 dob date like %d/%m/%Y 12-04-2019
```

Using problems() just expands on this message. I'm struggling to know how to proceed because whatever I change in col_date() doesn't seem help. In fact, it then reports (as can be seen above) that the opposite formatting was found in the file.

EDIT: Trying suggestion from Bernhard

I read in the column as character and ran the following:

```
head(data$dob, 20)

[1] "12/04/20" "20/04/2020" "20/04/2020" "20/04/2020" "20/04/2020" "20/04/2020" "20/04/2020" "20/04/2020" "20/04/2020" "20/04/2020" "20/04/2020"
[12] "12/04/2019" "12/04/2019" "12/04/2019" "12/04/2019" "12/04/2019" "12/04/2019" "12/04/2019" "12/04/2019" "12/04/2019"
```

Comment: Your error message suggest that row 1 of column `dob` first contains `12/04/2019` and then later `12-04-2019`. Have you changed your file in between getting these two error messages? Or opened it in other programs before saving it again, such as Excel?

Comment: If you read the data as character, how do the dates look like? Can you read it in as character and post the result of `head(data$dob, 20)`?

Comment: What about you read the data with that column as character and then converted it into a date with `lubridate::dmy()`?

Comment: Hi @jpiversen, I've not changed anything in the file or opened elsewhere so it's really confusing me as to why it thinks its 12/04/2019 and sometimes 12-04-2019!

Comment: @Bernhard Ran your suggestion and have posted as an edit to the original post

Comment: @AndreaM I did initially try lubridate::dmy() without success either. I get the following error even though the variable is present

Error in lapply(list(...), .num_to_date) : object 'dob' not found

Comment: Can you add to your post the exact `lubridate` code that you've tried?

Comment: Can you convert your character column with `as.Date` into a valid date as in `c("12/04/2020","21/04/2020","20/05/2021")|>as.Date("%d/%m/%Y")`? Are there any `NA`? Find them along the lines of `c("12/04/2020","blech")|>as.Date("%d/%m/%Y")|>is.na()|>which()` and see if you have a problem with the input data format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After suggestions from Bernhard, I found that there were inconsistencies with the input date format with different rows using different separators. I fixed this by converting them all into the same separators.